# How to fetch external file data like json format using angularjs service

Tags: angularjs

Hi i need external file data using angular service.Here my code i want this data to json format.

Controller code:

```js
$http.get('assets/scripts/modules/hawkColumnList.js').success (function(data){

    console.log(data);

});
```

Services code:

hawkColumnList.js

```js
  var resourceColumns = [
                    /* aggregation functions */
                    "resource_id",
                    "resource_name",
                    "resource_details",
                    "resource_address",
                    "resource_address6",
                    "resource_group",
  "resource_asset_criticality",
  "compliance_asset",
                    "pulse_templates",
                    "class_name",
                    "class_type",
  "eps_average",
                    "os_type_name",
                    "date_added",
                    "last_seen"

  ];
```

Comment: Make the content of hawkColumnList.js valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$http.get('assets/scripts/modules/hawkColumnList.js').success (function(data){

    var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\r|\n/g, '').match(/(\[.*\])/)[1]);
    console.log(dataJSON);

});
```

Explanation: The regular expression `\[.*\]` will grab everything from the string that is within square brackets, including the brackets. `JSON.parse` will parse that string into a JSON object (only working on standard browsers and IE>8)

Make sure that there are no syntax errors, which will result in parse errors leading to an undefined JSON object.

EDIT: Make sure that you remove the comment from the js file, because a comment inside a string is illegal with regards to JSON.parse. I edited the code above to remove line breaks first.

Check this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv8kdn0g/8/)

Comment: still have same issue i tried this but i got null data